# How to give dynamic varying space between words in Tcl?

Tags: list, arraylist, tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

I'm new to tcl ,I like your help to give a dynamic variable spacing between words in Tcl.
Example : "Stack over flow"
" Stack" as 5 letter in it.
So I have to give space of 5 to start next word same goes to next word.

```
Output: Stack     over    flow
```

Comment: `over` is 4 letters in length. Should it be `overf` instead? And did you try anything?

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly what you want to get out and what you put in. Surrounding those bits in `<pre>`…`</pre>` (just like in HTML) will help you make the page give exact spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
set example "Stack over flow"
set result ""

foreach word $example {
    append result $word [string repeat " " [string length $word]]
}

set result [string trim $result]
puts $result
```

Will give:

```
Stack     over    flow
```